# Collect and display a list of c++ TODO comments from the source code in emacs

Tags: c++, emacs

Our coding conventions allow to put comments like this in the code when we spot someting, e.g. during code review:

```
 // TODO(XY): do this
```

Now after pulling from the repository I always have to grep manually for `// TODO(ME)` which is bothersome esp. since the list is currently growing.

Question: how to display and manage such a list im emacs conveniently?

Comment: It's not really an answer to your question, but if you use Doxygen, you can use the tag `/** @todo do this */` in your code. It will generate a list in your dev doc.

Comment: M-x rgrep will open a buffer and clicking on the FIXME will open the file at the correct location. What do you want more than that? Importing them in org?

Comment: @ThomasMoulard that works well enough for now, thanks :) Why don't you post as an answer? Alternatively I can delete the question.

Comment: @Beginner I converted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution is using `M-x rgrep` which will open a buffer.  Clicking on the FIXME will open the file at the correct location.